# Get URL parameter from friendly URL value

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

i am using a url re write rule to change url to friendly.

my link now shows like this

http://domain.com/user/10002

what i am trying to do is if the user modifies the url uid under 10000 it will redirect to main page.

This worked before re write but not anymore

```
<?php


if(empty($_GET['user']) || $_GET['user'] <10000 ) {
    redirect(ROOT_URI);
    exit;
}
?>

RewriteRule ^user/([^/][0-9]*)$ user/profile.php?user=$1
```

Comment: post your .htaccess please. or debug with a print_r in your $_GET

Comment: cmnardi posted it

Comment: can you post var_dump($_GET['user']); ?

Comment: string(5) "10329"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `$_GET['user']` is a string you should change your code like this:

```
if(empty($_GET['user']) || intval($_GET['user']) <10000 ) {
    redirect(ROOT_URI);
    exit;
}
```

?>

Comment: ok but say user is 10002 and if you change the value and it don't exist can i make it redirect also?

Comment: this is another kind of problem, if 10002 is the id, you can check in your database if it exists. doing a query inside your if statement